# Liquid error: undefined method `map’

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, liquid, octopress

I'm trying to replace my Wordpress blog with [Octopress](http://octopress.org). It's a photo-blog so I decided to use the [photo_tag Plugin](http://tritarget.org/blog/2012/05/07/integrating-photos-into-octopress-using-fancybox-and-plugin) but have a problem. If I use the gallery syntax, I get:

```
Liquid error: undefined method `map’
```

What can I do to replace that map method? I googled a little and only found [this github issue](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/243) that tells me I have to use `liquid 2.2.2` but that doesn't seem like an option with `jekyll`.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating all your libs:

```
bundle update
```

and modify the Gemfile:

```
gem 'jekyll', '~> 0.11.2'
...
gem 'liquid', '~> 2.3.0'
```

then

```
rake generate
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Jekyll using liquid 2.2.2? It's hack-ish, but may work. Try modifying your `Gemfile`:

Replace `gem 'liquid', '~> 2.3.0'` with `gem 'liquid', '= 2.3.0'`

Comment: This doesn't change anything.